# What's difference between get and [] in Kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin

I currently have an element

`val test: map <int, List <string>`

I have a question which is the best way to obtain an element if

```
test.get (100) or test [100]
```

What is the difference, which has the best performance?

Comment: They result in identical bytecode.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html

Comment: For safety you could use as well `getOrElse` and `getOrNull`

Answer (score 3):

It is the exact same thing. In Kotlin, you can [override operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed). `[]` *is* the `get` operator, so the resulting jvm byte code will be exactly alike.

You can do the same thing with other operators, e.g. `plus`:

```
val x = 3 + 2
```

is the same thing as

```
val x = 3.plus(2)
```

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ, you can CTRL-click on the `[]` or the `+` operator and on the `get()` and `plus()` function respectively and you will see that you end up at the same place.